# Automatizar varias veces clic en un botón hasta que salga un resultado

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

hola quiero hacer mas de 5 veces clcik en un botón hasta que me salga un mensaje pero  no lo quiero hacer de la forma tradicional se que hay una forma angularJS

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Ejemplos")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[2]"));
```

Comment: Podes ser mucho mas claro en lo que necesitas? esta pantalla es tuya o estas haciendo click sobre otra pagina? cual es el problema que te genero este codigo?

Comment: cuando se da click en un botón por 6 veces, a la 6 vez sale un mensaje, lo que necesito es que a la 6 vez lea ya salio el mensaje puedes salirte

Answer (score -1):

podrias hacer algo así:

html

```
<button type="button" (click)="pulsador(5)">Pulsa</button>
```

angular

```
var i = 0;
pulsador(num){
  i++;
  if(i >= num){
    //mostrar el mensaje
  }
}
```

Comment: me parece que esta haciendo un scapping de pantalla, y quiere apretar en una que no es suya....